# Building Win7 Moneychanger: Where to put OT DLL's, How to fix "&& was unexpected" in jsoncpp?

Tags: windows, open-transactions

I want to use [Open Transactions](http://opentransactions.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) libraries in my Windows build of my Qt Widgets application. Moneychanger is a test interface for OT built in Qt. As a step to understanding how the Qt code of Moneychanger and the c++ code of OT interact, **I want to build Moneychanger on Windows 7 x64 with a binary distribution of OT .dll's.**

**I can't find documentation on including the OT library when I build Moneychanger.** The current documentation (which I'm happy to improve:) [git/readme.md](https://github.com/Open-Transactions/Moneychanger#development-and-manual-build-instuctions) / [git/doc/INSTALL-win.txt](https://github.com/Open-Transactions/Moneychanger/blob/21c3e9baf7b64d8aa66837ee4792e1e071b1664c/doc/INSTALL-windows.txt)

### Starting Conditions

- Windows 7 Professional x64
- Qt 5.3.0
- Qt Creator 3.1.1
- Visual Studio Express 2012
- Visual Studio Express 2013
- [Open-Transactions-0.92.c-Win32-setup.exe](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=77301.msg859040#msg859040)
- Clone [moneychanger source from git](https://github.com/Open-Transactions/Moneychanger)

### Compilation errors on MSVC/MinGW Qt compilers

- Open `project/moneychanger.pro` in Qt creator
- Configure Qt Creator kits with various compilers and QT versions, including MinGW 4.8.2, MSVC 2012 OpenGL 32bit, MSVC 2013 32bit, MSVC 2013 OpenGL 64bit
- Select "Debug" configuration
- Click Run button

#### Desktop Qt 5.3.0 MinGW 32bit ([Full Log](http://group.cambrian.org/pastebin/?b29486fa6f1775b7#sQ20knAIblbRrtEbvr0mXR22F2qhhyesqfUBEEPcZ7Y=))

```
<snip>
compiling ../../src/jsoncpp/jsoncpp.cpp
g++.exe: error: C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bigobj: No such file or directory
```

This [MinGW support answer](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/mailman/message/31588867/) seems to say that I need MSVC compiler for jsoncpp to compile.

#### Desktop Qt 5.3.0 MSVC2013 OpenGL 64bit

#### Desktop Qt 5.3.0 MSVC2013 32bit

#### Desktop Qt 5.3.0 MSVC2012 OpenGL 32bit ([Full log](http://group.cambrian.org/pastebin/?71d6dc2bd5f3422f#utcUZv+Lw4yab3eAv8fe/ObHekK0/fAfMGl7FjAuchA=))

```
<snip>
compiling ..\..\src\jsoncpp\jsoncpp.cpp 
...
&& was unexpected at this time.
...
13:53:19: The process "C:\dev\qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
```

### MSVC 2013

The next thing I tried was converting the Qt project into a Visual Studio "solution." In preparation for this I installed the Windows Debugger Tools in the [SDK for Windows 8.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/hardware/gg454513).

The file `doc/INSTALL-windows.txt` offers the instructions:

```
Open Visual Studio x86 2013 prompt.
change to the 'project' directory.
run: qmake -r -tp vc moneychanger.pro
```

I got the qmake command to work:

```
> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\cl.exe"
> cd C:\dev\project\moneychanger\project
> qmake -r -tp vc moneychanger.pro
  'qmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
C:\dev\project\Moneychanger\project>"C:\dev\qt\5.3\msvc2013\bin\qmake.exe" -r -tp vc moneychanger.pro
Reading C:/dev/project/Moneychanger/project/curl/curl.pro
Reading C:/dev/project/Moneychanger/project/libidn/libidn.pro
Reading C:/dev/project/Moneychanger/project/jsoncpp/jsoncpp.pro
Reading C:/dev/project/Moneychanger/project/bitcoin-api/bitcoin-api.pro
Reading C:/dev/project/Moneychanger/project/nmcrpc/nmcrpc.pro
Reading C:/dev/project/Moneychanger/project/moneychanger-qt/moneychanger-qt.pro
C:\dev\project\Moneychanger\project>
```

Now I have a `project/moneychanger.sln`.

#### MSVC Build Errors

Here's what happens when I build `project/moneychanger.sln` in Visual Studio 2013: ([Full Log](http://group.cambrian.org/pastebin/?0c05e20bbef5751f#Ww2TFe/VjyuA14KVtLEtt1eBqHCHZGcqYi0n/CzYksU=))

```
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'opentxs/stdafx.hpp': 
No such file or directory 
c:\dev\project\moneychanger\src\core\stable.hpp`
```

Sure sounds like I need to point Moneychanger at my OT library. I don't know how to do that in either Qt Creator or MSVC. For now I have da2ce7's binary v0.92c with `otapi.dll`, `otlib.dll` and more. Eventually I want to build a windows OT library myself and use that. For now I'll settle for the binary package.

Please tell me it's as simple as copying stuff around and rebuilding!